# I am trying to create a database with one .BKP file, but i don't have the .mdf & .ldf file, how do create a database without having these files

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a database with one .BKP file, but i don't have the .mdf & .ldf file, how do create a database without having these files.

```
RESTORE DATABASE MYDB
FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup Files-selected\MYDB_20170117\MYDB_20170117.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'test' TO 'C:\temp1\test2.mdf',
MOVE 'test_log' TO 'C:\temp1\test2.ldf';
```

> Error: Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   Logical file 'test' is not part of database 'MESDB'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: This is all pretty simple from the UI - is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

In **Sql Server Management Studio** (SSMS), right click on Databases and select **Restore Database...**

- Enter a Name for new DB.
- in the Source select "**From Device**" and select your **.bak.**
- Check the backup selected (restore column).
- go to "**Options**" Page and select "**Overwrite existing...**" (first option, With replace).

Hope this help!

Comment: It is giving the error : “The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing “myDB” database . RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3154)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using "RESTORE FILELISTONLY" command before the actual RESTORE command

RESTORE FILELISTONLY from disk  = 'C:\Backup Files-selected\MYDB_20170117\MYDB_20170117.bak'
RESTORE DATABASE MYDB
FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup Files-selected\MYDB_20170117\MYDB_20170117.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'test' TO 'C:\temp1\test2.mdf',
MOVE 'test_log' TO 'C:\temp1\test2.ldf';